# Alfresco Share 5.2 previewer issues

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco Share 5.2 and currently I am having a problem with previewing of the files.
When I upload file and open detail page, Adobe Previewer, which is used here, won't preview the file.
I can just see message like this: **Preparing previewer...**

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Problem is no with Adobe Previewer but libreoffice on server with preparing preview. Check logs if there is no error. Look at configuration for ooo.* in alfresco-global.properties. Check if soffice runing on specified port right.